# Calculating means with list data in R

Tags: r, list, mean, standard-deviation

so here is my problem: I have some code that extracts some data from 29 excel files and organizes anything labelled "sw" into one variable, and everything labeled "rep" into another variable:

```
file.number <- c(1:29)
data <-setNames(lapply(paste0(file.number,".csv"),read.csv,stringsAsFactors=FALSE),paste0(file.number,".data"))
n <- 1:29
df <- data.frame(RT=1:100,rep.sw=sample(c("sw","rep",100,replace=TRUE)))
sw <- lapply(data[n],function(df) with(df,na.omit(RT[rep.sw=="sw"])))  
rep <- lapply(data[n],function(df) with(df,na.omit(RT[rep.sw=="rep"])))
```

I want to then find out the means and standard deviations of these files, except when I used mean(sw) it tells me that "argument is not numerical or logical: returning NA". if I open "sw" or "rep" I get something like this:

$`28.data`
 [1] 0.8476 0.8362 0.5442 0.6987 0.7859 0.7396 1.0230 1.2446 0.8683 0.6049 0.6355 0.7421 0.9611
[14] 0.8074 0.9847 0.6291 1.0054 0.6969 0.7265 0.6452 0.7258 0.8099 0.6202 0.7873 0.6800 0.6932
[27] 1.4137 0.9585 1.6352 0.5182 0.9112 0.6410 0.7425 0.8477 0.6520 0.7538 1.0690 0.4945 0.6436
[40] 0.3885 0.6794 0.7635 0.7180 0.4817 0.6300 0.7036 0.6592 0.5893 0.7757 0.7562 0.9872 1.2523
[53] 0.6881 0.9567 1.2612 0.6691 1.0147 0.7342 0.5541 0.7812 0.8366 0.6086 0.3273 2.7230 1.1746
[66] 0.6796 0.5465 0.7613 0.7385 0.7043 0.6008 0.5958 1.1628 0.6029 0.6236 0.6968 0.9634 0.4779
[79] 0.7606 0.9773 0.7741 0.5647 0.8278 0.5899 0.5874 0.7234 0.5261 0.5980 0.5951
attr(,"na.action")
  [1]   1   3   4   5   7   9  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24  26  27  29  31  33  35  37  39  41
 [24]  42  44  46  47  49  51  53  55  57  59  61  63  65  67  69  71  73  75  77  79  81  83  85
 [47]  86  88  90  92  94  95  97  99 101 102 103 105 107 109 111 112 114 116 118 119 121 123 125
 [70] 126 128 130 132 134 135 136 137 139 141 143 145 147 149 151 153 155 157 159 161 163 165 167
 [93] 169 171 173 174 176 178 179 181 183 185 187 189 191 193 195
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"

$`29.data`
 [1] 0.6426 0.5946 0.6903 0.6798 0.7299 0.8263 0.6023 0.6095 0.5822 0.7946 0.5403 0.5716 0.6120
[14] 0.6508 0.5124 0.4831 0.5197 0.5750 0.5578 0.5993 0.7203 0.5777 0.5906 0.4900 0.5620 0.7961
[27] 0.5908 0.6904 0.5560 0.4818 0.4990 0.5240 0.5225 0.6483 0.6777 0.4982 0.6693 0.6540 0.5528
[40] 0.5033 0.5314 0.5208 0.5375 0.6032 0.5255 0.5439 0.4703 0.5123 0.6321 0.5057 0.5668 0.5387
[53] 0.5980 0.5555 0.5745 0.5961 0.5186 0.5541 0.5976 0.9179 0.6375 0.5769 0.5807 0.6663 0.6177
[66] 0.5507 0.4639 0.8702 0.5002 0.5325 0.4975 0.5741 0.5051 0.5476 0.8307 0.4861 0.6348 0.5990
[79] 0.5649 0.6674 0.5247 0.4840 0.5376 0.5241 0.6764 0.5281 0.6310 0.6082 0.5833 0.5424 0.5984
[92] 0.6329
attr(,"na.action")
  [1]   1   3   5   7   9  11  12  14  16  18  20  21  23  24  25  27  28  30  32  34  36  38  39
 [24]  41  43  45  47  49  50  52  53  54  56  58  60  62  63  65  67  69  70  72  73  74  76  78
 [47]  79  81  82  84  85  87  89  91  93  95  97  99 101 102 104 106 108 109 111 112 114 116 118
 [70] 120 122 123 125 127 129 131 133 135 137 139 141 143 145 146 148 150 152 153 155 157 159 161
 [93] 163 164 166 167 168 170 172 174 175 177 179 180 182 184 186 187 189 191 193 195 197 199 201
[116] 203 205 206 208 210 212 213
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"

Any help will be greatly, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sw` and `rep` objects are `list` objects and so you cannot directly use `mean` on them.

If you want the mean of each component of the list, you can:

```
    sapply(sw,mean)
```

Comment: Haha, I never thought it would have been so easy! Thanks!